# Trapezoidal Riemann Sum

Tags: code-golf, calculus

Given a list of coordinate pairs, output the Trapezoidal Riemann Sum of the values given between the first and last x-coordinates.

You will be given a sorted list of coordinate pairs, like this:

```js
[
  [1,2],
  [3,5],
  [5,11]
]
```

Note that x-coordinates will always be in increasing order, ys may not.

My way to do this is (you might find a different way):

Get pairs of coordinates:

```
[1,2],[3,5] and [3,5],[5,11]
```

For each pair (let's start with the first):

- Take the average of the y-values: (2 + 5) / 2 = 7/2
- Take the difference of the x-values: 3 - 1 = 2
- Multiply the two together to get the area of that section, which is 7/2 * 2 = 7.

Do this for all pairs. Let's quickly go through the next, [3,5],[5,11].

Average of y values = (5 + 11) / 2 = 8
Difference of x values = (5 - 3) = 2
Product of the two = 2 * 8 = 16

Now take the sum of all the values, resulting in 16+7 = 23.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

## Testcases

```
[ [1,2], [3,5], [5,11] ] => 23
[ [3,4], [4,1], [7,5] ] => 11.5
[ [0,0], [9,9] ] => 40.5
[ [1,1], [2,3], [3,1], [4,3] ] => 6
```

Note that input will always contain *non-negative integers*. Tell me if any of the testcases are wrong as I worked them out by hand.

You may take a flat list, or the list with x and y swapped.

Comment: Are you sure the second case is 10.5? 1*2.5 + 3*3 seems to equal 11.5

Comment: @hyper-neutrino That's why I said to check :p

Comment: I assume pairs can be given as `[y, x]`?

Comment: @dingledooper I assume that positive refers to nonnegative in this context.

Comment: @dingledooper Sorry for the confusion, I meant non-negative, as you can see from #3.

Comment: Is a flat list ok for input?

Comment: is @UnrelatedString 's format ok?

Comment: @UnrelatedString Yes that's ok

Comment: @Noodle9 Yes that's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 6 bytes

```matlab
@trapz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en99@hpCixoOp/mka0oYKxgmmsjkK0kYKpgqFhrCYXUNBYwUTBHCRoomAIlAWLGShYgkRAFJhvqGAE1GoCEgOZAcSxmv8B)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>54 49</s> 47 bytes

```ruby
->l{(r,=l).sum{|a|x,y,z,w=r+r=a;(y+w)/2r*z-=x}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nWqNIxzZHU6@4NLe6JrGmQqdSp0qn3LZIu8g20VqjUrtcU9@oSKtK17aitvZ/gUJadHS0oY5hrE60kY4xkDQGs02A7NjY/wA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
ṁΠTzẊe-o½+T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxnMLQqoe7upK1c0/tFc75P///9HRhjpGsTrRxjqmQNJUx9AwNhYA)

A rare question where you get to use a list of functions!

### Explanation

```
ṁΠTzẊe-o½+T
          T transpose
   z        zipwith
     e      list of 2 functions:
      -      difference
       o½+   average
    Ẋ       using pairwise reduce
  T         transpose back
ṁ           map to and sum:
 Π           product
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ạ+ƭ"P¥ƝSH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroXax9YqBRxaemxusMf/w@2Pmtb8/x@tEG2oYxSroxBtrGMKokx1DA1jFUAskJAJiGGiYwiizIEKoBIGOgYghqWOJUzEEKLGSMcYYpYhRKMxUB4A)

```
ạ+ƭ"P¥ƝSH  Main Link
     ¥Ɲ    For each (overlapping) pair
   "       Vectorize; apply to x coordinates then the y coordinates
  ƭ        Tie:
ạ          - for the x coordinates, absolute difference
 +         - for the y coordinates, sum
    P      Product
       S   Sum
        H  Halve
```

Comment: [-1 if you move the `H` to the end](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroXax9YqBRxaemxusMf/w@2Pmtb8/x@tEG2oYxSroxBtrGMKokx1DA1jFUAskJAJiGGiYwiizIEKoBIGOgYghqWOJUzEEKLGSMcYYpYhRKMxUB4A)

Comment: @UnrelatedString you have been ninja'd, my explanation is done already :P

Comment: ...ninjad by 4 minutes, no less
hmm

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda p:sum((b+d)*(c-a)/2for(a,b),(c,d)in zip(p,p[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxLbsMwDET3PgV3IVsmNf1pEQPqRVQv5DhGBPhDJHKK9vJuVGX1gHkzoz/hsszlNpivbXRT1zvQ5rZOiN1rTy942jt6K4blio47YjxxT36GX6@orFaalmj7vvjxDNJk4GdlWNagYGByiue7Gzmma0A63HT0AXdgPmFHlIFe/RxwwIcnhkQw5v@ANgtWuGgZbMl1RM0iLbRxXpSZjXkV84ol4uPRSlbkUEefcx7FkY9PUeVJSFoUXKZ7STfls/b@Bw)

Comment: You can use (c-a) instead of abs(a-c) because "x-coordinates will always be in increasing order"

Comment: @G B Missed that part, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Two more 9-byte answers:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Ḣ€IḋSƝF$H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkWPmtZ4PtzRHXxsrpuKx////6O5FBSiDXWMYnVADGMdUwjDVMfQMJYrFgA)

## and [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ZIḋSƝ}ɗ/H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/K8@GO7uBjc2tPTtf3@P//fzSXgkK0oY5RrA6IYaxjCmGY6hgaxnLFAgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

I don't think there are as many 9-byters as in Jelly, but here is one:

```
ø`ü+;s¥*O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I6Ew3u0rYsPLdXy//8/OtpYxyRWJ9pExxBImuuYxsYCAA)

```python
          # implicit input                                      [[1,2],[3,5],[5,11]]
ø`        # tranpose and push x and y seperately to the stack   [1,3,5], [2,5,11]
  ü+      # for y coordinates: sum adjacent numbers             [1,3,5], [7,16]
    ;     # halve each value to get means                       [1,3,5], [3.5,8.0]
     s    # swap to x coordinates                               [3.5,8.0], [1,3,5]
      ¥   # get deltas, consecutive differences                 [3.5,8.0], [2,2]
       *  # element-wise multiplication                         [7.0,16.0]
        O # take the sum                                        23.0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>60</s> 52 bytes

```r
function(l)diff(l[1,])%*%(c(l[,-1])+l)[2,-ncol(l)]/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc3NCsIwEATge58iIIWsTjWbH6WH@iKlB4kECjGFGsG3rxEvrcxh5/AtMy95fnZLeCWfxynJSPcxBBl7xkD1vpa@dDQ80CFSr9EkP8WihpP@fsrHLc/juyiGhoErYSZoIiF2orsKbaqNM7AljAvcmjEf3RYqKLRo18iqf8T47ZpyLcwan6vlAw)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>55</s> 45 bytes

```r
function(x,y)diff(x)%*%(y[-sum(x|1)]+y[-1])/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LCsJADEX3fsWAFBKN2syj4qL@iHQ1MtCFLfQBU/DfpxO0XVzC5ZxwhzQNY53C3Pmp7TuItOC7DQEiFqcCltdlnD8Qv4zNORdu8KblBTwwGXJIHjQ5YkZU6qjqp9Lm8BMMWbqLYImzuXHmq/sbJT2Ey9moLXfKpPOEFUO2cnarSis)

*-6 bytes thanks to @Dominic*

---

For input as matrix:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 50 bytes

```r
function(a)diff(a[1,])%*%(a[2,-ncol(a)]+a[2,-1])/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc3BCsIwDAbg@56iIINWf7VpV2WH@SKyQ6kUCm6DWsG3r1UvnfyHJOQLiTnFx5D9c3YpLDO34ha85/ZKGEW7bUunsJ/dci@rcfedaBRH9bnjk00xvLjjBAUNU0IkoIRgbMOGC1O6WTmNroRwhqkZ0cGsoYREj75GnfxHhN9fXWoHXeNTk98)

Comment: If it's Ok to accept a list of ```x```s & a list of ```y```s, I think you can get [even shorter](https://tio.run/##PY3LCsIwEEX3fkVAChO9aicPxUX8EekqUujCFPqAFPz3mKDtYu4szrncIU3D6FI7Bz91faCIBcGN85vih6V8dW1LUVaHipbnKTTHnNzIiyo18sTQsBKeFCw4F4TYC/cQSu9@gobBrQgGnM2VM5/t36hxL7y8lZp6owyVJ0wxyla@zbqmLw)...

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks. That lead to further golfing it down.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
×Ø-+PʋƝSH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9MMzdLUDTnUfmxvs8f9w@6OmNZH//0dHK0Qb6hjF6ihEG@uYgihTHUPDWIVYHa5okJAJSMhExxBEmQMVQCUMdAxAIpY6ljARQ4gaIx1jiFmGEI3GQPlYAA)

Assumes the second test case is in fact meant to be 11.5. Although I did admit to trying this while it was still in the Sandbox like ten minutes ago, this contains absolutely none of the code I tried while it was there :P

Comment: Also 9 bytes: [`NÐo+PʋƝSH`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/v8IR87YBT3cfmBnv8P9z@qGlN5P//0dEK0YY6RrE6CtHGOqYgylTH0DBWIVaHKxokZAISMtExBFHmQAVQCQMdA5CIpY4lTMQQosZIxxhiliFEozFQPhYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
n=>n.reduce((z,[a,b],i)=>z+=i--&&(b+n[i][1])*(a-n[i][0])/2,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc2xDoIwGATg3adgMq38xf4UYhjKizQdChRTQ1oD6sDLVwujOt0NX@5u5mWWfnb3B/NhsHGU0cvWF7Mdnr0lZAVloNPgqGzXXDrGjkfS5V45rVDTEzFs61zTcwmcxj74JUy2mMKVjERlCqHUkCkBdYoaEHWmKT18QQFVEhVgisvH/3YceAINNH8A7gsliP0Y91mx8fgG)

Doing it with `map` is just as long:

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
n=>n.map(([a,b],i)=>z+=i--&&(b+n[i][1])*(a-n[i][0])/2,z=0)&&z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc2xDoIwGATg3adgalr5iy2FGIbyIs0/FARTgy0R48DLVwujOt0NX@5u9mWX/uHmJ/fhMsRRR69bX9ztTKmx0CE4pts1145zQmiXe@PQSGRHavnWBbJTCasWjJA19sEvYRqKKVzpSE1mJJQImVFQp6hBSsyQscMXVFAlUYFMcf74306ASKCB5g@Q@0IJaj@W@6zaeHwD)

---

Thanks EliteDaMyth for saving 1 byte off both answers (was a general tip)

Comment: according to testing, `i--&&(...)*(...)/2` is 1 byte shorter than `i--?(...)*(...)/2:0`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda l:sum((y[0]-x[0])*(x[1]+y[1])/2for x,y in zip(l,l[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCoMwEADQfU@R5cSOtKO4ETzJdBaWEgyMMfiBxMun2TxezOeyhb7oxEzYCXKPQ3VAIpGHmz5F5/X7m42Ox7UCZH5Lmyq2gcQkz1yxr85tu0mYjQ/m9hEUlWkUa0vcfTjBgdb/AQ)

-2 bytes thanks to @NahuelFouilleul

Comment: You can unpack each value of the sublists as well, although that would make your answer identical to dingledooper's.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

Given \$n\$ coordinate pairs, this computes \$\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(y_i+y_{i+1})/2\times(x_{i+1}-x_i)\$ recursively.

```javascript
f=([[x,y],...a])=>a+a?([[X,Y]]=a,y+Y)/2*(X-x)+f(a):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc5RC4IwEAfw9z7FHrc8585pYWB9DWXsYZhGIS4yQj/9cihU2L0cHPe7/93My/TV43p/hp091841OVVqgFED59xolh9NYE7TrIBS69zAGJQsire0CAcWNNSwg3CV7Xrb1ry1F9pQRRRCrIEoCalvKSBqohkjS0URieVmpSQkfj0B9G0/4W/kFSJP106A8CCD7Bd8XCL@OZyDYpDzsziny@XK5HbuDQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), 56 bytes

```perl
s;(\d+),(\d+)(?= (\d+),(\d+));$\+=($3-$1)*($2+$4)/2;ge}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYo7CgIxFAD7PUWEVyTmRfPyQZYQPIE3SCO4yoK4wdiIeHWfwcpmYJip0/0aGUpeteMTynyGkrglWU5a4Y9yn8WfqgRFZwneAKm1BKchqK1Ll@n9YiZ0wmMUEYkGj0EEJLHDOFi0YsRxoO4OfZ@oN/9Z6mNebo1NZXOIG0tf)

`-M5.01` option and `say($\),$\=""if$\;` header are needed only to run all tests otherwise the program works for one line.

example: `perl -pe 's;(\d+),(\d+)(?= (\d+),(\d+));$\+=($3-$1)*($2+$4)/2;ge}{' <<< '1,2 3,5 5,11'`

trick: `-p` option with `}{` at the end so that continue block is not executed on each iteration but at the end, and `$_` is empty so only `$\` is printed

deparse: `perl -MO=Deparse -pe 's;(\d+),(\d+)(?= (\d+),(\d+));$\+=($3-$1)*($2+$4)/2;ge}{'`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 11 bytes

```
ÞT÷2lvṁ$¯ȧ*
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C3%9ET%C3%B72lv%E1%B9%81%24%C2%AF%C8%A7*&inputs=%5B%5B3%2C4%5D%2C%5B4%2C1%5D%2C%5B7%2C5%5D%5D&header=&footer=)

```
ÞT          # Transpose
  ÷         # Push each to stack (y is on top
   2l       # Groups of 2
     vṁ     # Averaged
       $    # Swap to get x coords
        ¯ȧ  # Deltas
          * # Multiply the two
            # Sum that.
```

There's probably a better way :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 63 bytes

```
\d+
*
|""L$vm`^(_*),(_*)¶\1(_+),(_*)
$.3*$($2$4
^(__)*
$#1
_
.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYoxCsJAEEX7f4w4wmYzhMzOLiHMFexsgxtBCwtTiFh5rhzAi60rNg8e7z2uz9t6lrJ3x8XKfOng8W6aA73uy8ll3/IPn20Wl7u/gHr15ChQRF1y60E7QUafShEOppwssQiUo0UWGzlh4MEmniDVA2udpDb9Ag) Takes newline-separated pairs but link is to test suite that splits on semicolons for convenience. Explanation:

```
\d+
*
```

Convert to unary.

```
|""L$vm`^(_*),(_*)¶\1(_+),(_*)
```

Match overlapping sets of four values from two lines.

```
$.3*$($2$4
```

Multiply the difference between the first and third value by the sum of the second and fourth value.

```
^(__)*
$#1
_
.5
```

Divide by 2 and convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 16 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÕÌä+ í*UÕÎäa)x÷2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=1czkKyDtKlXVzuRhKXj3Mg&input=W1sxLDJdLFszLDVdLFs1LDExXV0)

```
ÕÌä+ í*UÕÎäa)x÷2     :Implicit input of array U
Õ                    :Transpose
 Ì                   :Last element
  ä+                 :Consecutive pairs, reduced by addition
     í*              :Interleave with, reducing each pair by multiplication
       UÕÎ           :  Last element of transposed U
          äa         :  Consecutive pairs, reduced by absolute difference
            )        :End interleave
             x       :Reduce by addition
              ÷2     :Divide by 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>74</s> 72 bytes

-2 thanks to @ceilingcat

```c
a;r(int*x){for(a=0;~x[2];)a+=(x[2]-*x)*(*++x+x++[2]);printf("%f",a/2.);}
```

Takes input as a flat list terminated with `-1` (e.g. `{x1, y1, x2, y2, ..., -1}`)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/haoMwFIV/N08hQiHRa2cSuzGCT1L7I7OxFLa0OAcBca/uTmq3mQO5uffLPTdpi3PbzrM1Pb/4IQti7K49t3VpvsNBHY2wec3jqQDLeJbnAcpREObWo6Xj6bZLyT6pnTDTjEoyuM9hcaPT9evt3SUu3Fw7uJMYWZL0PAiD@Nve@G3X@AKr8Sn9XTVsYizafdiL5@jcxCTIw7EeJSnStIekpEJO5gFVhJoqSNIL8IrpyEoq6RVa1avFcLHUiBX2O2eb@08CkMZzHpnCzN3@P8e4cp1X9BzfPv8A)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>78</s> 75 bytes

-3 (indirectly) thanks to @ceilingcat

```c
a;r(int*x,int*y){for(a=0;~*++x;)a+=(*x-x[-1])*(*y+++*y);printf("%f",a/2.);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBha4MwEIY/N79ChEI0Z2di2jGCv6T2Q2a1FDZbrIML4v66u9h1y2CBhOThuZfL1dmprufZmp6fuyFF8KdLxvbSc1vm5jMVAk1iRclTzHCfyUOS8tQJIUgz1578lsfrNgb7pDaJmWYi0dDchjAQjpeP17cmavDa1ENzTEYWRT1HoAy6PWKqbt1WXUar6mL4kQ2bGPOx7/bccapd@QfK/aEcJRSwhUxO5k7dQhUxKQOMyuMCNDyH8kI1yD8RWHiaw0to/sNQ3xtQ4HMDVz8a83vhbLVMBCU48gv60TdQ4BR1utn@ogIc5eUh0uA07Pwc5i8) Takes input as a list of `x`s and a list of `y`s, terminated with `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 70 bytes

```
1k[sysxdly+2/syrdlxr-sxrlxly*lad1+sa:az4!>L]dsLxc[la1-ddsa;ar0<L+]dsLx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcgxDoAgDADAr@AqIVrURY0v4AfEoaFxsRNdip@vxtx2VAxcdJNbPgAGd5YmStx8HKRVYq1BtLJy6xkJvOCKz9wd6SRJWjIjBCLBDeu4J/@vXfYC)

One decimal place of precision (`1k`) is sufficient because the longest fractional part we can have is 0.5. There could be better ways of twiddling the bits around.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
Ｉ⊘ΣＥΦθκ×⁺§ι¹⊟§θκ⁻§ι⁰⊟§θκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyMxpyw1RSO4NFfDN7FAwy0zpyS1SKNQRyFbU0chJDM3tVgjIKe0WMOxxDMvJbVCI1NHwRAoE5BfABcCK9YECvpm5qGqNMCuEgKs//@Pjo421jGJ1VGINtExBFHmOqaxsbH/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     θ                      Input array
    Φ                       Filtered on
      κ                     Current index
   Ｅ                        Map over tail
         §ι¹                Current Y-coordinate
        ⁺                   Plus
            ⊟§θκ            Previous Y-coordinate
       ×                    Multiplied by
                 §ι⁰        Current X-coordinate
                ⁻           Minus
                    ⊟§θκ    Previous X-coordinate
  Σ                         Take the sum
 ⊘                          Divide by 2
Ｉ                           Cast to string
                            Implicitly print
```